# how to get Min values for dimension members?

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012, mdxstudio

I have a cube with few dimensions. Report Date and Account are two of them. One account id may come under multiple Report dates. I need to find minimum report date for every accountid. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please add some code so we get an idea of the structure of your cube?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something similar -

```
WITH SET[MinDate] AS
    Head(NonEmpty(
            ReportDate.[ReportDate].[ReportDate].MEMBERS, 
            {(EXISTING [Account].[AccountId].CurrentMember , [Measures].[foo])}
            ),1)

SELECT [MinDate] ON 1,
[Account].[AccountId].MEMBERS ON 0
FROM [bar]
WHERE [Measures].[foo]
```

If what you want is the minimum date's value, then you would need to get that in a calculated measure instead of a set.

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[MinimumDate] AS
    Head(NonEmpty(
            ReportDate.[ReportDate].[ReportDate].MEMBERS, 
            {(EXISTING [Account].[AccountId].CurrentMember , [Measures].[foo])}
            ),1).ITEM(0).Name
```

Comment: Hi Sourav - does that definitely work? I'm not sure if a named set will pick up context ok - you could probably just swap it to a calculated member instead easy enough. Worth testing against AdvWrks.

Comment: Rookie mistake!! Fixed it. Also added an approach for the date value, instead of selecting on axis. Thanks for pointing out the error.